# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler (Date)

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to pass the value from an element. Unfortunately I get the error message.
ErrorMessage: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numerischer oder Wertefehler

```
declare
    l_von date := to_date(:P2061_DATE_FROM,'dd.mm.yyyy'); -> ErrorMessage ORA-06502
    
    l_von date := to_date('01.01.2020','dd.mm.yyyy'); -> works
begin
```

In the :P2061_DATE-FROM field the selected date is transferred to the user.

I think I have to somehow convert this value into a DATE value?

This is part of the entire code:

```
declare
    l_date_string varchar2(32000);
    l_date_diff number(4);
    l_von date := to_date('15.06.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
    l_bis date := to_date('23.06.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
    l_script varchar2(32000);
begin

   l_date_diff := l_bis - l_von;
   
   for g in 0..l_date_diff loop
    l_date_string := l_date_string ||''','''||to_char(l_von+g,'dd.mm.yyyy');
   end loop;
   
   l_date_string := substr(l_date_string,3)||'''';
```

Comment: What data type is `P2061_DATE-FROM`, what value does it have, and if it's being converted from one data type to another as part of this call, what are they and what format is being applied?

Comment: It is a hidden field. There is page 2060, a modular dialog. Here the user enters the start date in a date field and the end date in another date field. Then page 2061 is called up and both values ​​are passed in the two hidden elements P2061_DATE_FROM and 2061_DATE_UNTIL.

Comment: I just checked what value is passed in the hidden field. It was 20.06.20 - Now I have adjusted the format mask and it will be transferred 20.06.2020.

Comment: What is the full error you get "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large" ?

Comment: Yes,  that is the only error that is displayed:  ORA-06502: PL / SQL: numeric or value error / There are no further details as to whether the number precision too large or otherwise. That's why I'm so surprised.

Comment: OK, but can you get the same error by using a fixed date literal instead; or get rid of it by avoiding the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you have a german version of Oracle installed. For the future I would highly recommend you translate everything into english if you are asking questions as people mostly wont go translating it for themselves just to see if they can help you with your question.

But for now, it would appear the :P2061_DATE_FROM item is not the correct type.
For what you are trying to do, either have the item be a DATE PICKER and then in the function leave out the whole to_date thing.

Or you could have it be a TEXT FIELD and use the to_date as is.

Comment: Excuse me. You're right. I'll take that into account next time. Unfortunately, your two ideas don't work. There are two hidden elements. These are transferred from page 2060 (modular dialog) through two date fields. I once took away the TO_DATE and only wrote: P2061_DATE_FROM. The same error message appears. If I change the elements into date fields, it doesn't work either. Neither with TO_DATE nor without.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an implicit conversion issue. I can replicate it (I think) with a fixed date:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    l_date_string varchar2(32000);
    l_date_diff number(4);
--    l_von date := to_date('15.06.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
    l_von date := to_date(date '2020-06-15','dd.mm.yyyy');
    l_bis date := to_date('23.06.2020','dd.mm.yyyy');
    l_script varchar2(32000);
begin

   dbms_output.put_line('l_von: ' || l_von || ' => ' || to_char(l_von, 'SYYYY-MM-DD'));
   l_date_diff := l_bis - l_von;
   
   for g in 0..l_date_diff loop
    l_date_string := l_date_string ||''','''||to_char(l_von+g,'dd.mm.yyyy');
   end loop;
   
   l_date_string := substr(l_date_string,3)||'''';
   dbms_output.put_line(l_date_string);
end;
/

l_von: 15-Jun-20 =>  0020-06-15

Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

The problem is that I am doing:

```
l_von date := to_date(date '2020-06-15','dd.mm.yyyy');
```

and it seems that your version with:

```
l_von date := to_date(:P2061_DATE_FROM,'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

is doing the same thing - that is, that the value you are passing is already a date, not a string.

The debug I added shows the issue:

```
l_von: 15-Jun-20 =>  0020-06-15
```

The `to_date(<date>,'dd.mm.yyyy')` is really having to do `to_date(to_char(<date>),'dd.mm.yyyy')`, and that `to_char()` is using the session NLS_DATA_FORMAT to convert the date to a string, in my case with the common (and I think still default) DD-MON-RR pattern, giving a two-digit year. So then you're doing `to_date('15-Jun-20', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`, and the YYYY format element is converting '20' to year 20 (0020), not 2020.

So far that's sort of valid, but wrong. Then you do `l_bis - l_von`, which evaluates as `date '2020-06-23' - date '0020-05-15'`, and that is 730526. Which is also valid, but wrong.

The error is then being thrown when you try to assign 730526 to `l_date_diff`, which is defined as `number(4)`, and obviously that value is too big for the declared precision.

```
declare
    l_date_diff number(4);
begin
    l_date_diff := 730526;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

While there are a few ways you could work around that, the sensible option is to not do any conversion, and declare and assign your local variable as:

```
l_von date := :P2061_DATE_FROM;
```

or skip that variable and just use the Apex variables directly:

```
declare
    l_date_string varchar2(32000);
    l_date_diff number(4);
    l_script varchar2(32000);
begin

   l_date_diff := :P2061_DATE_UNTIL - :P2061_DATE_FROM;
   
   for g in 0..l_date_diff loop
    l_date_string := l_date_string ||''','''||to_char(:P2061_DATE_FROM + g,'dd.mm.yyyy');
   end loop;
   
   l_date_string := substr(l_date_string,3)||'''';
```

You could also use `listagg` to build the date list string, but it would involve a context switch and might not be any simpler.

Comment: It is a very good approach. Thank you very much!

I think the problem is the content of the element I want to pass. I tried manually to pass the variable l_date_diff the value '5'. - it works

But, l_date_diff := :P2061_NEW; - it does not work
Das Element ist ein normales Textfeld mit dem vorher festgelegten Wert 5. Und trotzdem bekomme ich dann die Meldung: ORA-06502: PL / SQL: numeric or value error

That is, somehow he cannot process the element. Strange